# Having trouble in adding number in 0.0 decimal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, coffeescript

i am using react.js for some of my views! i changes my column max_budget to decimal and added default as 0 so now the default is 0.0! 
i have a button and on clicking it, it adds 2 to max budget every time it is clicked! the problem i am facing that!
the default is 0.0 and every time i click the button to add 2 to that 0.0 to make it 2.0 it messes it up and add 2 at the end on 0.0 as 0.02 and if i press it few times it keep added 2 at the end like 0.022222
the button code is:

```
  changeTip: (e) ->
e.preventDefault()
name = e.currentTarget.name # http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_currenttarget.asp
if name == "increase"
  max_budget = @props.max_budget + 2
else
  max_budget = @props.max_budget - 2
data = max_budget: max_budget
@props.saveJobValues(data)
```

how should i fix it so on adding 2 it shows me 2.0 instead of 0.02

Comment: Apparently `@props.max_budget` is a string instead of a float. You can use `parseFloat(@props.max_budget)` to cast it to float.

Comment: @props.max_budget is a decimal defaulted at 0.0

Comment: parseFloat works good! now it work fine and make that 0.0 to 2 if i add 2! but i doesn't add 2.0 it just adds 2 i want it to 1 decimal place!

Comment: In the database it may be a decimal, but in this piece of code it's a string.

Comment: and everytime i type 0. in the box it makes it nil! the "." makes it nil

Comment: And 1 more question how to enable textfield to take decimal number! because right now if i add " . " before of after any number it make sthe whole textbox to null. @Mischa

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML5 with

```
<input type="number" min="1.0" max="5.0" step="0.01">
```

to accept only float values as input. It will accept "." followed by number also, but reject ".", (`<input type="number" min="1" max="5">` for decimals.)

Change your code to

```
  changeTip: (e) ->
e.preventDefault()
name = e.currentTarget.name # http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_currenttarget.asp
if name == "increase"
  max_budget = parseFloat(@props.max_budget) + 2.0
else
  max_budget = parseFloat(@props.max_budget) - 2.0
data = max_budget: max_budget
@props.saveJobValues(data)
```

(add parseFloat as @Mischa mentioned). I recommend to write "2" as "2.0" for readability (so it's easier to see that you deal with floats)

Comment: tried! but still rejecting " . " and making the field null

Comment: even if i write "2." or " . " it makes the field null

Comment: wich browser (version, mobile?, os) do you use? One out of http://caniuse.com/#search=number ?

Otherwise use a polyfill
https://github.com/jonstipe/number-polyfill

Or you'll have to check for NULL

Comment: using chromo latest version, using Mac IOS and one more think i am doing this in REACT.JS